# Why is installed application too big?

Tags: android, android-studio

Yes i know there are similar questions but i couldnt see any problem there.

I analyzed it with Android Studio Tool
[image]

Installed on Android 6.0.1 and in Phone installed application it says ~42 MB?!?!

I have deleted some data there and it went down to ~16MB.
I dont understand why is it so big i dont have images or anything its just simple app with edittext that sums values.

PS. On android 4.2.2 it have ~4MB which is fair size.

Comment: Android 5 and 6 pre-compile dex files native code (OAT). Those pre-compiled binaries are pretty large as they contain the original full DEX file.

Comment: So is there anything i can do to reduce size on newer android versions